# The check_path for login method is not matched by the firewall pattern

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.5

I'm configuring the security layer for a login form on Symfony2, but this error keeps emerging:

```
InvalidConfigurationException: Invalid configuration for path 
"security.firewalls.gestor_area": The check_path "^/ES/gestor/login_check" 
for login method "form_login" is not matched by the firewall pattern "^/ES/gestor".
```

The relevant part of **security.yml** is:

```
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    gestor_area:
        pattern: ^/ES/gestor
        http_basic: ~
        provider: db
        form_login:
            login_path: weblogin_login
            check_path: ^/ES/gestor/login_check

    access_control: 
           - { path: ^/ES/gestor, roles: ROLE_ADMIN } 
           - { path: weblogin_login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY } 
           - { path: ^/ES/gestor/login_check, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY } 
           - { path: ^/PT/project, roles: ROLE_ADMIN } 
           - { path: ^/FR/project, roles: ROLE_ADMIN } 
           - { path: ^/CL/project, roles: ROLE_ADMIN } 
           - { path: ^/ES/project, roles: ROLE_ADMIN } 
           - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

Made it fully work http autentification -- also displaying the login form, but when I try to authenticate with the login form it crashes, or it just display this error.

How do I set the route to match with the firewall pattern?

UPDATE: 
Added paths to Access Control, still doesn't work, same error.

Comment: You need to add also `- { path: ^/your-login-path, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }` and `- { path: ^/your-login-check-path, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }` to the access control to get accessible these routes.

Comment: update your post, delete the comment and let us know what doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

There's a typo in:

> The check_path "^/ES/gestor/login_check"

This `check_path` should be a plain text path and not a regex pattern. i.e. Leave out the `^` character in your case.

Comment: for using parameters in url you can use existing route aliases, for example, app_login_check

Answer (score 0):

You can use my admin fire wall it works for me.
I use jms i18n translation rooting bundle with fos user bundle and sonata admin bundle.

```
    admin:
        pattern:            /admin(.*)
        context:            user
        form_login:
            provider:       fos_userbundle
            login_path:     sonata_user_admin_security_login
            use_forward:    false
            check_path:     sonata_user_admin_security_check
            failure_path:   null
        logout:
            path:           sonata_user_admin_security_logout
        anonymous:          true
```

Answer (score -3):

Following the [Symfony Best Practices](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/security.html):

> Unless you have two legitimately different authentication systems and users (e.g. form login for the main site and a token system for your API only), we recommend having only one firewall entry with the anonymous key enabled.

So your configuration settings could be like this:

```
firewalls:
    secured_area:
        pattern: ^/
        anonymous: true
        form_login:
            check_path: security_login_check
            login_path: security_login_form
```

Take a look at the chapter for more information

Comment: This doesn't answer the question in any way.